# Record and Replay of MMS(Media Player) in LoadRunner

Tags: load-testing, loadrunner

Need to benchmark the performance of Windows Media server. The videos are hosted on this server.To access these videos, MMS(Microsoft Media Services) hyperlinks are provided in the web page.

Load Runner doesn't have the option of adding both Web(HTTP/HTML) and MMS(Media Player) protocol in Multiple Protocol while creating a new project.

Any other alternatives would be much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Configured mms.lrp File - [Configure MMS(Media Player) in Multiple Protocol List](https://community.saas.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-Practitioners-Forum/Function-mms-play-cannot-passed-more-than-2-vusers-when-running/td-p/589038)
2. Created a new script - Multiple Protocol with MMS(Media Player) and Web(HTTP/HTML).
3. Recorded the scenario and manually wrote the script using MMS(Media Player) Function API.
4. Successfully Compiled and was able to replay the script.

Answer (score 2):

> "Load Runner doesn't have the option of adding both Web(HTTP/HTML) and
>   MMS(Media Player) protocol in Multiple Protocol while creating a new
>   project."

That is **not true**.

When creating a new script, Loadrunner lets you choose bothe MMS and HTTP after selecting "Multiple Protocols" from the categories list:

[image]

Once you choose them both, you can record your browser action (opening your MMS links) and the MMS functionality.

Comment: MMS(Media Player) is the option I am looking for, not the MMS(Multimedia Messaging Service)